# How to transform floating action button into a toolbar upon press?

Tags: android, material-design, android-animation, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottomNavigationView currently, But I want to convert it into something like [this](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0B8v7jImPsDi-RTk1QkNaZnpneHM/components-buttons-fab-transition_toolbar_02.mp4). Are there any examples or sample codes for this transformation?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use this library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262407/how-to-transform-floating-action-button-into-a-toolbar-upon-press#
It's work perfectly

Comment: @BenoitCanonne You just posted link to this exact question